# VS 2008 use of component class and ...!?

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, dotnetnuke

What is COM..?/

Comment: You should ask a more detailed question, explaining what you want to do. What component class? Trying to achieve what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is a very general question, so not easily to answer. You might want to give more details about what you are looking for.

COM means Component Object Model. There is a long article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model